# how to convert the gps coordinate format (DMS) which i am extracting from geotag pictures to decimal format?

Tags: android, gps

the format of GPS coordinate i m getting is like 12/1,56/1,21047/10000 and 77/1,32/1/112316/10000. how to convert it into decimal format so that i can pass it to google map to get the location?

Comment: Can you show your method for getting these coords? Android's Location classes return doubles for latitude and longitude. These numbers don't make a lot of sense.

Comment: M Using exif interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 12/1,56/1,21047/10000
```

seems to be
12 degress (12 / 1) = 12
56 minutes (56 / 1) = 56
and 21,047 seconds (21047 / 1000)

So that is  `12°, 56' 21,047"`

Formula for DMS to DEG conversion:

```
decimal degrees = degrees + minutes/60.0 + seconds/3600.0
```

This gives: 12 + 56 / 60.0 + 21.047 / 3600.0 
= `12,939179` decimal degrees.

Same for the other coordinate

Comment: thats ok but the denominators i am getting is not constant. in some phone its 1,1,10000 and others its 1,1,100

Comment: so i need a method that will convert my format to the proper DMS format so that i can use the formula specified

Comment: it is a simple method that you can write easily yourself: return degrees / denom + minutes/denom / 60.0 + seconds / demom / 360.0;